# PostgreSQL COPY ERROR Invalid syntax. How to set data from dump?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a database dump, and I need to import it into a new empty database.

```
COPY public.accounts_account (id, username, password, first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip, daytime_phone, evening_phone, email, membership, total_purchase_amount, current_discount, registered_at, membership_approved) FROM stdin;

53  user53  password53  Name53  Last53  afd462740737a3801e90c6d050e81b88    Wilmette    IL  60091   123.456.786     user53@obfuscated.com   7590    102.00  0   2011-03-24 03:52:23+00  t
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "53"
LINE 4566: 53 user53 password53 Name53 Last53 afd462740737a3801e90c6d05...
           ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "53"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 132900
```

Comment: have you tried to put the `53` is quotes (simple or double)

Comment: @MickaelB. same error. And `53` is the value for the `id` field, which should be an integer

Comment: Did you check the line before this one? Maybe something with the line break? Also you have one missing field in this line (phone nr). Might be an empty string though.

Comment: Was there a proceeding error message?  Something like `ERROR:  column "registered_at" of relation "accounts_account" does not exist`?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using exactly `psql` utility to load this dump? Lets say: only `psql` program is able to execute the script created by `pg_dump` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Your COPY command failed for some reason (table doesn't exist, column doesn't exist, you don't have permissions to insert into it, etc.).  Since PostgreSQL did not go into COPY mode, it tried to interpret the next line as another command, rather than as data. Look earlier in your log file to see what the initial error is.

Answer (score 0):

This database dump looks like a query you can run from PG Admin's Query Tool but it is not and that is why your getting this error.

Copy paste everything in that database dump into a PSQL session and it should run correctly.

You can usually launch a PSQL session from PG Admin from the Tool drop down.